# Remove all the word after a particular word

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove all the words, numbers, hexadecimal numbers after a specific word ".c:"

my line is like that-

```
line = "Bags has a price.c:123
line = "Bags has a price.c:543ea
```

I have tried with the following:

```
d = re.sub(r'[.c:\W+]', '', c)
```

But it not giving right answer, the output will be like:

```
output: Bags has a price
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> line = "Bags has a price.c:123"
>>> line.split(':')[0]
'Bags has a price.c'
>>> line.split('.c')[0]
'Bags has a price'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> line = "Bags has a price.c:123"
>>> ''.join(line.partition('.c')[:2])
'Bags has a price.c'
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than the `.split` approach. `.partition` is too often overlooked in general IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a regex — and clearly you don’t. You could have done this:

```
re.sub(r'\.c:.*?$','', line)
```

If you can avoid the regex, then do. It’ll likely be much slower that using split.

Answer (score 0):

And just using a simple index lookup.

```
>>> line = "Bags has a price.c:543ea"
>>> after_word = ".c"
>>> cleaned_line = line[:line.index(after_word) + len(after_word) ]
>>> cleaned_line
Bags has a price.c
```

To exclude `.c` just remove the `+ len(after_word)`